# How to save/load Set type by NSUserDefaults?

Tags: swift, swift2

I am using Swift and have a Set type that contains Int:

```
var setA : Set<Int>
```

How to save/load this Set type by using `NSUserDefaults`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Convert the `Set` to `Array` which can be saved in `NSUserDefaults`

```
let arrayA = Array(setA)
NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(arrayA, forKey:"mySet")
```

and get the array and convert it back to `Set`

```
let arrayA = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("mySet") as! [Int]
let setA = Set(arrayA)
```

---

If you register the key/value pair as Apple recommends

```
let defaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
let defaultValues = ["mySet" : [Int]()]
defaults.registerDefaults(defaultValues)
```

the value is never `nil` and can be safely unwrapped.

Comment: vadian, you still have to cast result of NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("mySet")

Comment: probably NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("mySet") as? [Int] ?? [Int]() will better fulfill OP needs ... it shouldn't crash due to a wrong key, and registering default is no more necessary. I up-voted your answer, because i didn't know about registerDefaults() till now, thanks for that!

Comment: It's up to the developer to take care of proper keys and registering defaults is highly recommended even to avoid an optional.

Comment: I agree. The trouble could happen if later he use a statement  as NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(nil, forKey: "mySet") or NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(["a"], forKey: "mySet") etc. The compiler will not complain, and code will crash.  ... as? [Int] ?? [Int]() helps to avoid crash and yes, it could produce another wrong behavior silently ... It is always about personal preferences, i prefer don't crash my code, so using if let or guard let seem to be the best approach, if  default value could lead to something wrong.

Comment: The concept of Swift's type safety is not for supporting carelessness of the developer to transfer all responsibility to the compiler and guard **all** optional values to death even if that guard case will never happen. There are many many lines in Apple sample codes unwrapping optionals which are guaranteed to have a value.

Comment: @user3441734 NSUserDefaults has a specific method called arrayForKey  https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSUserDefaults_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSUserDefaults/arrayForKey: for loading array objects conditional cast from [AnyObject] to [Int] still needed